# find_if in set in C++: unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, set, stdset

I have used find_if before with lists and vectors in C++ and it has worked fine. But now, when I try to use it with sets I get the following error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘find_if(std::set<A, Acmp>::iterator, 
 std::set<A, Acmp>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’|
```

My class is the following:

```
bool searchForA(A i) {
   return (i.getVal() > 0);
 }


void B::findA()
 {
   set<A, Acmp> cont;
   set<A, Acmp>::iterator it;
   A *a1 = new A(5);
   A *a2 = new A(7);
   cont.insert(*a1);
   cont.insert(*a2);

   it = find_if (cont.begin(), cont.end(), search)
}
```

Can anyone help me understand where is the problem?

Comment: No I have not included that inside class A for the set. IF I may ask, why would overloading < affect find_if?

Comment: How about declaring `search (A const &i)`

Comment: That's a lovely way to leak memory. The pointers are completely unnecessary. By the way, [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3v0m5c%247) is close and works.

Comment: set element needs to be weak ordered, try to add `operator<` your code should compile, also as chris mentions, your code leaks memory

Comment: Is the definition of the `search()` function you gave above exactly the same as in your code? And is it the only definition for that function, or are there any overloads?

Comment: Ok, so I changed the name of the function, and I added to the set a Comparator. I will take care of the pointers too.

Comment: Sorry I take that back. Apparently the name of the function was the problem.

Comment: @billz The OP apparently uses a customised comparator `Acmp` for the set. So, adding a `operator<` won't change anything. Also, the comparison operator isn't relevant when `find_if` is used.

Comment: @jogojapan yeah, looks like it. I think Dave's answer is on the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a function in the STL called `search`. That's probably why the compiler can't resolve the right name without a better hint. You could rename your search function. Or if you don't want to do that, try passing `::search` into `find_if` instead.

Comment: That's what I thought initially too. I tried to change the name of the function. Still the same error.

Comment: No, changing the name of the function does fix that error. You're getting another big error because A needs a comparison operator, like the other people said.

Comment: Yes changing the name fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one function named `search` — the name is overloaded. To pass a pointer to `search` into `find_if`, you need to specify which one. The most straightforward way is to specify `static_cast< bool (*)( A ) >( cont )`.